# can I download a raw file from Google's cache?

Tags: download

I want to download a file that is in Google's cache at `webcache.googleusercontent.com`. It is a plain text source code file and I would like to download it as a raw file so that it is intact. The Google cache pages have a header and a certain amount of escaping is made in the original content.

Yes I can cut and paste but I was hoping to get the original file with its md5 intact.

I can't see a way to do this... does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears it is not possible to get md5 intact. I can make it work though on http://archive.org/web/ They save plain text file intact.

Comment: Yes I also did that, it's a good solution as long as what you want has been cached by archive.org.